# Cuando realizo una request en postman recibo status 500

Tags: java, api, spring, http, postman

Estoy trabajando en una api utilizando spring. Hice 2 entidades (provincia y localidad). Localidad tiene una llave foránea que lleva a la id de provincia, sería un @ManyToOne. El tema es que cuando realizo una request en postman recibo status 500 si en el json que envío uso:

```
{
    "descripcion": "Lanús",
    "provincia": {
        "id": 2
    }
}
```

Y sí funciona si cambio el "provincia" por "provinciaId", pero en ningún lugar del código uso "provinciaId":

```
{
    "descripcion": "Lanús",
    "provinciaId": {
        "id": 2
    }
}
```

No estaría entendiendo porqué

Entidades:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "provincias")
public class ProvinciaModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "provin_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "provin_descripcion")
    private String descripcion;

/**Siguen el constructor y los getters and setters*/

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "localidades")
public class LocalidadModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "local_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "local_descripcion")
    private String descripcion;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "local_provin_id")
    private ProvinciaModel provincia;

    public LocalidadModel() {

/**Siguen el constructor y los getters and setters*/
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ILocalidadRepository extends JpaRepository<LocalidadModel, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT l FROM LocalidadModel l WHERE (:provincia is null or l.provincia = :provincia)")
    List<LocalidadModel> findLocalidadByProvincia(@Param("provincia") ProvinciaModel provincia);

}
```